# iOS 8- viewController my_shouldAutorotate crash while presentViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, crash, ios8, presentviewcontroller

i am using Uinavigationcontroller as windows root view controller. IN some otherview i am presentingviewcontroller but my app is crashing in iOS 8.It was working perfect in ios7. It says

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
'-[InfoVC my_shouldAutorotate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15cd42780'.
```

where InfoVC is viewcontroller. what is my_shouldAutorotate

Comment: In your InfoVC class write following method:
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}

Comment: Thanks @ChanchalRaj... I wonder why didn't you post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your InfoVC class write following method: 
`-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{ return NO; }`